# Dynamic Array pop method is working but error in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, dynamic-arrays

I am implementing a dynamic array in java. My pop method should copy the array in a new array with one item less. The method works however I am receiving an error when testing with assert.

this is the pop method:

```
public int pop() {
data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length-1);
return data.length;
}
```

this is the JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testLargePop() {
    DynamicArray a = new DynamicArray(10);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        a.push(i);
    }
    for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
        assertEquals(i, a.length());
        assertEquals(i, a.pop());
        assertEquals("pop should reduce the length of a dynamic array by 1", i-1, a.length());
    }
}
```

This is failure trace:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<100> but was:<99>

The failure is on this line:

```
assertEquals(i, a.pop());
```

The failure is saying expected 100 but was 99, however pop is supposed to reduce length to 99. So that means the pop method is working. So I can't understand why I am still receiving error.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion

```
assertEquals(i, a.pop())
```

is never `true` because `a.pop()` decreases the array size by one. Therefore the assertion

```
assertEquals(i - 1, a.pop())
```

is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop the iterator i equals 100. That makes the inital 100 items match in the first assert. The next assert still compares the iterator value 100 to the length of the now shorter array. 100 != 99.